# how use memorycache in this method?

Tags: asp.net-core, memorycache

how can i add memorycache in this method ?
this is a section of my code that i want to set memory cache on it.

```
 public IActionResult Index(int pageId = 1, string filter = "",
           int startPrice = 0, int endPrice = 0, string getType = "", string orderByType = "date",
             List<int> selectedGroups = null, List<int> selectedBrand = null, List<int> selectedTags = null
            , List<int> selectedsize = null , string Discount = "")
        {

            ViewBag.selectedGroups = selectedGroups;
            ViewBag.selectedTags = selectedTags;
            ViewBag.selectedsize = selectedsize;
            ViewBag.Discount = Discount;
            ViewBag.getType = getType;
            ViewBag.Groups = _productService.GetAllGroup();
            ViewBag.Tags = _productService.GetTags().Where(c => c.ActiveRow).ToList();
            ViewBag.size = _productService.GetSizes().ToList();
            ViewBag.pageId = pageId;
            return View(_productService.GetProducttype(pageId, filter, startPrice, endPrice, getType, orderByType, selectedGroups, selectedBrand, 24, selectedTags, selectedsize, Discount));
        }
```

Comment: Why can't you add the memory cache as described in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-6.0 ?

Comment: Could you please tell me which data you want to cache?  The data which the client has returned or else? We need firstly know why and which data you want to store then we could suggest the right cache method to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

public Constructor (IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}

public IActionResult Index(int pageId = 1, string filter = "",
       int startPrice = 0, int endPrice = 0, string getType = "", string orderByType = "date",
         List<int> selectedGroups = null, List<int> selectedBrand = null, List<int> selectedTags = null
        , List<int> selectedsize = null , string Discount = "")
    {

        ViewBag.selectedGroups = selectedGroups;
        ViewBag.selectedTags = selectedTags;
        ViewBag.selectedsize = selectedsize;
        ViewBag.Discount = Discount;
        ViewBag.getType = getType;
        
        var groups = new List<Group>();
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("groups", out groups)
        {
            ViewBag.Groups = groups;
        }
        else 
        {
            groups = _productService.GetAllGroup(); 
            _memoryCache.Set("groups", groups);
            ViewBag.Groups = groups;    
        }
        
        var tags = new List<Tag>();
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("tags", out tags)
        {
            ViewBag.Tags = tags;
        }
        else 
        {
            tags = _productService.GetTags().Where(c => c.ActiveRow).ToList();
            _memoryCache.Set("tags", tags);
            ViewBag.Tags = tags;
        }

        var sizes = new List<Size>();
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("sizes", out sizes)
        {
            ViewBag.size = sizes;
        }
        else 
        {
            sizes = _productService.GetSizes().ToList();
            _memoryCache.Set("sizes", sizes);
            ViewBag.size = sizes;
        }           
        

        var pageId = null;
        if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue("pageId", out pageId))
        {
            ViewBag.pageId = pageId;
        }
        else 
        {
            _memoryCache.Set("pageId", pageId);
            ViewBag.pageId = pageId;
        }
                    
        return View(_productService.GetProducttype(pageId, filter, startPrice, endPrice, getType, orderByType, selectedGroups, selectedBrand, 24, selectedTags, selectedsize, Discount));
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).